# Plotting mean x and mean y for bins with equal numbers in ggplot?

Tags: r, ggplot2

I want to divide a population into groups with equal # of people. Then plot a point at mean X & mean Y for each group.

I'm using stat_summary_bin and quantile breaks in ggplot2. This plots mean Y but X plotted is at the mid-point of quantile.

Toy example with a population where the lowest quantile makes this easy to see:

```
library(tidyverse)
score <- rnorm(95, mean = 100, sd = 5)
score <- c(2, 6, 19, 77, 79, score)
height <- rnorm(100)
df <- data.frame(score, height)

low_pop <- filter(df, score < 80)
mean_low_pop1 <- mean(low_pop$score)
mean_low_pop2 <- mean(low_pop$height)

quantiles <- quantile(df$score, probs = seq(0, 1, 0.05))

ggplot(data = df, aes(x= score, y = height)) +
         stat_summary_bin(fun.y = mean,
                          geom = "point",
                          breaks = quantiles) +
  geom_vline(xintercept = mean_low_pop1)
```

Is there a way to let stat_summary_bin know how to plot the x axis? Or an alternate way? Thanks

Comment: Calculate the points you want to plot using `dplyr`, `data.table` or `aggregate`. Then give `ggplot` the data you want to plot. While it's nice that `ggplot` has some data aggregation features, when you want to do some data manipulation that's a little unusual, it's easier to make a data manipulation package do it than a plotting package.

Comment: `ggplot` is pretty good at summarizing things on the y-axis, but not very good at summarizing along x. So I agree with Gregor.

Comment: thanks both! have done as suggested - can't believe how much time i spent trying to make ggplot do this the hard way :)